# Self referencing loop detected for property with type

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 instances, Author, EventInstance, and Comments. An author can write a comment. People (authors) can add comments to an EventInstance. Here's the model.  I keep getting the following error.

```
public class Author
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   //..

   public List<EventInstance> Events { get; set; } 
          = new List<EventInstance>();
   public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
          = new List<Comment>();
}

public class EventInstance
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid AuthorId { get; set; } //Author FK
   //..

   public Author Author { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
          = new List<Comment>();
}

public class Comment
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }   //Author FK      
  public Guid EventId { get; set; }

  public EventInstance Event { get; set; }
  public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried several ways to fix but nothing seems to be working. Even a simple query like:

```
var list = await db.Events
            .Include(e => e.Author)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Thank for helping.

## EDIT

Here's my context class

```
public class EventContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EventInstance> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public EventContext(DbContextOptions<EventContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<EventInstance>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Author)
            .WithMany(a => a.Events)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.AuthorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Event)
            .WithMany(e => e.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.EventId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Author)
            .WithMany(a => a.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.AuthorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

I'm using a Factory for add and run migrations

```
public class EventContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<EventContext>
{
    public EventContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString =
```

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");

```
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EventContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new EventContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

And this is the startup class

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<EventContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IEventService, EventService>();
    }
}
```

I hope all the relevant pieces have been pasted here.

Comment: It should not fix your problem, but still I would argue that `[ForeignKey("EventInstance")]` should be `[ForeignKey("Event")]`

Comment: This is Json serialization issue, not EF (Core).  You can find many related posts by searching Web/SO with the error message. Here is one related to Azure Functions https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/685

Answer (score 0):

You should consider normalizing the structure to avoid the double referencing. For instance, if Authors have a collection of event instances and event instances have a list of comments then authors can get their comments through event instances.

```
public class Author
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   //..

   public virtual ICollection<EventInstance> Events { get; set; } 
          = new List<EventInstance>();
}

public class EventInstance
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Author")] 
   public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
   //..

   public Author Author { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Event")]
  public Guid EventId { get; set; }

  public EventInstance Event { get; set; }
}
```

Then to get the Comments for a particular Author:

```
var commentsForAuthor = context.Authors
    .Where(x => x.Id == authorId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Events.SelectMany(e => e.Comments))
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if Comments can be treated as a top-level entity (/w DbSet)

```
var commentsForAuthor = context.Comments
    .Where(x => x.EventInstance.AuthorId == authorId)
    .ToList();
```

Typically you would use Projection to get details about a comment, it's associated event, and author. (Using `Select`) This can navigate through the relational structure to get the appropriate details.

You likely can apply mapping expressions to remove the error with explicit mapping, but I'd recommend removing the denormalization. The trouble with the denormalization the references so that Author can have a collection of Comments is that there is no way to enforce that a Comment's Author reference matches the Author of the Comment's EventInstance. I.e. I can have an author ID 1, with EventInstance ID 1, and create a Comment with ID 101. Nothing stops me from changing that Comment's Author ID to 2. Now I have two sources of truth as to who the author is. `Comment.Author` (ID: 2) and `Comment.EventInstance.Author`. (ID: 1) Wherever possible, remove those duplicate reference paths.

EDIT: Mapping feedback

With mapping references and back, you will want to avoid double-mapping in the sense of mapping a relationship from both entities. Map relationships from one side. You could try:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventInstance>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Author)
        .WithMany(x => x.Events)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventInstance>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Comments)
        .WithOne(x => x.Event)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
        .Ignore(a => a.AuthorName)
        .HasMany(x => x.Comments)
        .WithOne(x => x.Author)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

}
```

Edit #2: If Authors can create comments for another author's events, then I would suggest removing the Comments relationship from the Author side. Comments can be retrieved as a top-level entity or through the Events as a top level entity.

For instance:

```
public class Author
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   //..

   public virtual ICollection<EventInstance> Events { get; set; } 
          = new List<EventInstance>();
}

public class EventInstance
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
   //..

   public Author Author { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid EventId { get; set; }

  public virtual EventInstance Event { get; set; }
  public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
  public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
  
}
```

Then in mapping:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Author)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Event)
        .WithMany(x => x.Comments)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
        .Ignore(a => a.AuthorName);
```

This switches around the mapping from the Event over to the Comment, but the Comment maintains a bi-directional reference to it's Event, but a single-direction reference to its Author. (`HasMany()`) This should satisfy EF's mapping. On a side note with the explicit relationship mapping using `OnModelCreating` or `IEntityTypeConfiguration` we don't need the `[ForeignKey]` attributes so I removed those.

Comment: An author can add a comment to an event he/she didn't create. In that case, should I make `authors` and `comments` a `many to many` relationship? I'm afraid it may not solve the problem.

Comment: If that is the case, that authors can create a comment for a event they didn't create, then I would remove the "many" relationship on the Author from comments. I'll update my answer to outline that option.

Comment: Anything you propose didn't work in `Azure Function`. I was so curious that I implemented the original model in ASP.NET Core MVC, i.e. an author can add an event. The event's author or any other author can comment to an event. The same code that was causing problem in Azure Function worked just fine in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Are other entity relationships working as expected within Azure Function?

Comment: no. I removed every navigation property from all the entities and all the configuration. I run the migration then update database. So, all 3 tables don't have a FK. I run the simplest query `var list = await db.Events.ToListAsync();`. I still got the same problem both on `Azure` or on `MSSQLLocalDB`.

Comment: Hmm, then I suspect the issue is more something missing or out of date configuration with Azure Function and EF. You are using a `FunctionsStartup` class to add and initialize the DbContext? I.e. `public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)` and `builder.Services.AddDbContext<yourDbContext>(options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString));`  No guarantee that's up to date with the latest EF Core and Azure Functions.